# Is it possible to create a BulletDecorator using the current theme?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I'm using the well known technique of styling a list box to look like a radio button group.
The style presents a BulletDecorator for each item in the list.  In order to do this I need to reference a specific theme assembly such as PresentationFramework.Aero.dll, and then explicitly use that in my style.

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

<BulletDecorator.Bullet>
    <theme:BulletChrome 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" 
        IsRound="True" 
        RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding UIElement.IsMouseOver}" 
        IsChecked="{TemplateBinding ListBoxItem.IsSelected}" />
</BulletDecorator.Bullet>
```

Is there a way to create a BulletDecorator which is styled using the current or default theme, so that I don't need to reference an explicit theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to recreate the `RadioButton` template... why don't you just use a `RadioButton` in the `ItemContainerStyle`?

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonGroup" TargetType="ListBox">
  <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" GroupName="ListBoxItems" />
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that there's an issue with this approach: if you use this style for several `ListBoxes` in the same window, *all* `RadioButtons` will be mutually exclusive, because they will share the same `GroupName`. See [this article](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2010/11/15/radio-groupname-scope) for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes my particular problem - I don't need to reference a particular theme any more.  Also since the items are effectively grouped by the listbox, GroupName isn't required, so there's no issue as far as I can tell, but I'm setting GroupName="{x:Null}" for safety anyway.  I suppose the more general question of 'if I do need to explicitly use some chrome in a control, do I have to reference a theme?' needs a separate question.

Comment: @Phil, the GroupName *is* required, because the RadioButtons are not directly in the same panel. I know because I tried before I posted my answer ;).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to unaccept this answer (hopefully temporarily).  When using a RadioButton instead of a BulletDecorator the selected item binding is ok when using the keyboard, but doesn't work when using the mouse.

Comment: @Phil, I reproduced the issue. The fix is to replace `{TemplateBinding IsSelected}` with `{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}`

Comment: Hey, nice one.   That's not the first time that's bitten me :-)  You deserve another up vote.